# Error using remote_api_shell.py: ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I'm tyring to use `remote_api_shell.py` to access the datastore of my Google App Engine application in the following way:

```
remote_api_shell.py -s url/of/server --secure
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./remote_api_shell.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "./remote_api_shell.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 160, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 156, in main
    oauth2=True)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 74, in remote_api_shell
    secure=secure)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 768, in ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 835, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 569, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 245, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 562, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1584, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1268, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1014, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/home/vagrant/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away when I switched from using my custom domain name to `my-app-id.appspot.com`.

**Some other considerations**:

1. If you are using https, then `your-app-id.appspot.com` will not work out of the box. You have to enable it on the Google Apps page corresponding to the domain name. Yes, that means that you will actually have to have Google Apps setup for that domain.
2. If you have a multi-module setup, make sure you add `remote_api: on` to the `builtins` section of the `app.yaml` of the **default** module. Or if you have `remote-api: on` for another module, then use the url that skips the `dispatch.yaml` file and targets the module directly.